# Binary Search Tree a Sub-category of Binary Tree?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I was asked the following question on an exam:

> What is the name of this data structure (algorithm used to fill the
>   data structure, as covered by the textbook)?

[image]

I answered that it was a binary tree, but my professor marked it wrong, saying that it was a binary search tree.  **My question: Is a binary search tree not a "sub-category" of binary tree?**  My thought, in the context of his question, was that binary tree was the broadest answer possible(thus safest).

I have seen varying answers to similar questions asked on the web, and even this site, with some going as far as suggesting that a BST is only an algorithm for binary trees (vs a stand-alone data structure).

Comment: I guess you were supposed to notice that the nodes were sorted.  A related question is: Is there a use for binary trees *other* than sorting?

Comment: @Kingsley I have to assume that is what he wanted us to notice, but the wording of the first part is what I got hung up on. Also, you mean to suggest you feel he hinted at bst?

Comment: Yes I guess he hinted it's a BST.  But I also do agree marking you wrong is splitting hairs.  What if the answer was "tree" - is that also correct?  Maybe he really wanted the *search* in there.

Comment: Another term may be a *sorted* Binary Tree.

Comment: Relax, kid.  10 years from now none of this will make the slightest difference.  I agree that it's a _bad_ question though.  A binary search tree doesn't look any different from a regular binary tree on paper.  How do we know that the intended use of the tree was searching?  It could be that the nodes were sorted by _coincidence_.

Comment: @Kingsley: Yes, there are uses for binary trees that are not sorted. The 'rope' data structure for instance uses an ordered but not sorted binary tree (each node holds a sub-sequence of a larger overall sequence). Even the classic self-balancing algorithms (RB and AVL) do not strictly require sorting, sorting is simply the usual mechanism to determine where in the tree a new node belongs but other schemes are possible (current caret position as one example).

Comment: Could also say that it is a balanced binary tree.

Comment: Question has two hints “algorithm to fill” and “according to textbook”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BST is a binary tree but according to information that were provided - you was able to give better answer. (BST)